# How do you reclaim disk space after adding an alternate in git?

Tags: git, reference, diskspace

I have a git working directory and have added to `.git/objects/info/alternates` so that this working directory does not need to store duplicate data that's already in another working directory on my machine.  (This is what `git clone --reference=DIRECTORY` does).  However, duplicate objects already stored in the working directory aren't deleted from my `.git/` directory.  This means the `.git/` directory stays large.

How do I get rid of the duplicate objects so the `.git/` directory is smaller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git repack -adl
```

The `-l` option in particular omits objects that are borrowed from an alternate.  See `git help repack` and `git help pack-objects`.

Comment: Use [`-f` to not reuse deltas for optimal packs](https://manned.org/git-repack#:~:text=%2Df%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Pass%20the%20%2D%2Dno%2Dreuse%2Ddelta)